# DML on Territory Object

Tags: apex

While I am trying to do DML in Territory object, I am facing the issue that "dml not allowed on territory type". Anyone can help me on this? how can I perform DMl operation on territory Type object ?

Comment: Just remember: altering territories may be a significant recalculation of records, so you may cause org locks while this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Salesforce some standard objects don’t support DML operations although you can still obtain them in queries. Territory is one of the object where you can not perform DML operation, Way out to achieve this requirement you need to take help of Soap and Rest API. To make it more simple you can call javascript function and in the the javascript function you can perform the DML operation (Insert/Delete) on territory object. I have done this in my DE and it is wokring fine.Please let me know if you want me to share the code snippet.